# Continuity of an Integral over an unbounded region

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, continuity

Fix $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Define $$F(x,y)=\int_{-\infty}^x f(s,s-y)\,ds,$$ where $f(x,y)$ is the joint pdf of continuous random variables $X,Y$. I want to show that $F(x,y)$ is continuous at every $y\in\mathbb{R}$.

I started my preliminary analysis as this: Fix $y_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ and let $\epsilon>0$. For an appropriate choice of $\delta$, suppose $|y-y_0|<\delta$. Now
\begin{align*}
|F(x,y)-F(x,y_0)| &= \Big|\int_{-\infty}^x f(s,s-y)\,ds - \int_{-\infty}^x f(s,s-y_0)\,ds \Big| \\
&\le \int_{-\infty}^x |f(s,s-y)-f(s,s-y_0)|\,ds.
\end{align*}

Of course, the end should be $|F(x,y)-F(x,y_0)|<\epsilon$. Right now, I'm looking to bound $\int_{-\infty}^x |f(s,s-y)-f(s,s-y_0)|\,ds$ using maybe the continuity of the pdf $f(x,y)$ or the fact that $|y-y_0|<\delta$.

If the region were some bounded interval $(a,x)$, for some $a<x$, I know for a fact that there exists some $\delta>0$ such that $|f(s,s-y)-f(s,s-y_0)|<\frac{\epsilon}{x-a}$ due to the continuity of the pdf $f(x,y)$. And thus $|F(x,y)-F(x,y_0)|<\epsilon$. But I am having difficulty finding the correct choice for $\delta$ (in terms of $\epsilon$) primarily because of the unbounded interval of integration $(-\infty,x)$.

Your suggestions (even if it's a totally different approach) will be appreciated a lot.

Comment: Is $f$ assumed to be continuous?  The problem statement never said it was.

Comment: Yes, $f$ is continuous in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Answer (score 0):

This is false, even assuming that $f$ is continuous (which is not stated in the problem!).  Let me write $g(x,y)=f(x,x-y)$ for convenience.  Now imagine that $g$ is a function which is $0$ except on a sequence of wide (in the $x$-direction) but short (in the $y$-direction) rectangles where it has a steep bump, where the $x$-coordinates of the rectangles approach $-\infty$ and the $y$-coordinates of the rectangles approach $0$.  (The shortness of the rectangles is so that the total integral of $g$ can still be $1$, and the $x$-coordinates approach $-\infty$ so that $g$ can still be continuous at $y=0$.)  Then $F(0,y)$ can be large for values of $y$ approaching $0$ (namely, $y$-coordinates in the middle of the rectangles), but $F(0,0)=0$.

Comment: Thank you Eric for your response. But $g$ (or $f$) does not behave like that on your example. $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ is a probability density function (take for example the bell-shaped pdf of a bivariate normal distribution).

I don't know which property/properties of $f$ to use in my proof. I know $f$ is smooth, bounded and continuous. I believe it is also uniformly continuous based on its graph.